# How to pass a SQL temp table to a C# stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, temp-tables

What's the best way to pass a temp table to a C# stored procedure (SQL 2008)? Am I stuck passing the temp table name as text and running a select from C#?

I was hoping to use Table Value Parameters, but they don't appear to be supported in C# sprocs.

Comment: CLR stored procedure != extended stored procedure. Writing an extended stored procedure is so much different and is more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the text above. I'm actually porting some old C++ extended sprocs to C# stored procedures. The C++ kept state between calls, and I'm attempting to move the state into temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

As xml (perhaps as nvarchar(max)) would be your best bet, but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, TABLE type parameters are not supported [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx). You have other options though, eg. pass state as a BLOB ([SqlBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.aspx)) or as XML ([SqlXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.aspx)).